# MYSQL Before Update Trigger Issue

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I am creating a trigger on wordpress database table wp_options but everytime it gives syntax error.

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 6

Here is my Trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER WpafDbDefaultTableRenameTrigger 
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON wp_options
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.option_name = "wpaf_db_table_name" AND NEW.option_value != OLD.option_value THEN
          SET NEW.option_value = CONCAT("wp_",NEW.option_value);
          RENAME TABLE OLD.option_value TO NEW.option_value;
        END IF;
       END;
```

I tried solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27326788/mysql-before-update-trigger-giving-error). After using this solution my trigger was

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER WpafDbDefaultTableRenameTrigger 
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON wp_options
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.option_name = "wpaf_db_table_name" AND NEW.option_value != OLD.option_value THEN
          SET NEW.option_value = CONCAT("wp_",NEW.option_value)$$
          RENAME TABLE OLD.option_value TO NEW.option_value$$
        END IF$$
       END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But got same error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems with your trigger:

1. Syntax:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER WpafDbDefaultTableRenameTrigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON wp_options
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF NEW.option_name = "wpaf_db_table_name" AND
      NEW.option_value != OLD.option_value
   THEN
   /*
      SET NEW.option_value = CONCAT("wp_",NEW.option_value)$$
      RENAME TABLE OLD.option_value TO NEW.option_value$$
   END IF$$
   */
      SET NEW.option_value = CONCAT("wp_",NEW.option_value);
      RENAME TABLE OLD.option_value TO NEW.option_value;
   END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

2. [RENAME TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/rename-table.html) cause an implicit commit:

> Explicit or implicit commit is not allowed in stored function or
>   trigger. See [13.3.3 Statements That Cause an Implicit Commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html).